# Specific commit push on the remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch on both local and remote. I have done a number of commits on master branch and have pushed them to remote as well. 
Now what I have created a new branch x on remote and want to push the only latest commit to that branch not all commits which I have pushed to remote master.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly? Are you trying to push local commits to the remote branch 'x' and not the remote master branch? To do that I believe it's:

```
git push remote x
```

or if the local branch with commits has a different name:

```
git push remote src_branch:dest_branch
```

It's not that clear what you're trying to do though, if you could explain the problem in more detail that would help.

Comment: Actually there are two branches on remote 1. dev and 2. testing. What I want is development commits should be there on dev and when we are done with development the only the stable commit to be pushed to testing branch not all which are there on dev.

Comment: Ah ok. So say you have a local branch 'testing', you can create a new branch based on that with 'git checkout -b dev testing'. Then do your development commits on the dev branch. When you're done, merge those back into the testing branch: 'git checkout testing; git merge dev'. Then use 'git rebase -i' to select the commits you want, and push that to remote.

Comment: The only problem is, if you do things like including the latest commit but removing an earlier one, the checksums will change so you'll get merge conflicts if you try to merge the dev branch in again. So it's best to only remove the last commit (or the last 2, or 3 or whatever).